# Do I need to retain autoreleased objects?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest library and I want to be sure if I use it in a good way from the memory management point of view.
I create:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:someUrl];
```

I guess that according to the naming convention I don't have to retain request object, right?
but when I look at the code of requestWithURL:someUrl method I can see:

```
+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)newURL
{
return [[[self alloc] initWithURL:newURL] autorelease];
}
```

so the returned object is autoreleased. Shouldn't I retain it in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general no - as it is autoreleased, its retained by the autorelease pool and that will release it when it goes out of scope. However, you can retain and then release it if you are in a situation where you need the extra security that provides.

Comment: But then, if I don't retain the object it is possible that the autorelease pool will release it and I will end up with an invalid object, right?

Comment: It depends on your architecture, but I don't think so (I've not had any errors myself, put it that way) however, if you have scope to retain then release you will not do any harm!

Answer (score 5):

If you use autorelease object within a method, you should not retain, so this is okay:

```
- (void) myMethodDoRequest
{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:someUrl];
    // use request within this scope only
}
```

If you want to store the autorelease object in ivar, you have to retain to expand the lifecycle of the object, and latter release to avoid leak:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    ASIFormDataRequest *request;
}
```

and

```
- (void) myMethodStoreRequest
{
    [request release];
    request = [[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:someUrl] retain];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [request release];
}
```